# The electric tension connected to an X-ray tube

Tags: electromagnetism

The maximal frequency from an X-ray tube is 8.4 ·1018 Hz And I'm trying to figure out the tension, voltage, connected to the x-ray tube

So far I have

hf max = eU

where e = ?? Elemtary charge of an atom? h = ?? Plancks constant? f = ?? frequency?

But I do not understand why that formula would work, what that formula describes, and how the electric tension relates to the x-ray tube

Comment: FYI, in English it sounds very old-fashioned to use the word "tension" like that except in certain set phrases (like "high tension wire"). The contemporary usage is to say "potential" or "voltage".

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your X-ray has frequency $ 8.4 \times 10^{18} Hz$, which is realistic. To determine the energy of one photon, use

$ E=h\nu$, with Planck constant $h = 4.135 \times 10^{-15}eV s$ - electronvolts unit simplifies it.

Multiplication gives me energy almost 35 keV, i.e. you should have tension (almost) **35kV** on the tube.

You accelerate electron to 35 keV energy and convert to Xray. Read more [on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung#X-ray_tube) about the process.

remark: Your $hf$ is the same as $h \nu$, $e=1$, because I am in electronvolt units. You could redo the calculation in SI units, taking $h=6.626 \times 10^{-34} Js$ and electron charge $e= 1.6\times 10^{-19} C$.